# How to update an object all elements inside map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update object all elements one by one in map, It is updating only one element of the object not all

```
 const [docUrls, setDocUrls] = useState({
    imageUrl: "", panUrl: "",statementUrl: ""
  })
```

response from api

```
res.data.map(item=>{
          if(item.type === 'image'){
            setDocUrls({...docUrls, imageUrl:item.url})
          }else if(item.type  === 'pan'){
            setDocUrls({...docUrls, panUrl:item.url}) 
          }else                   
            setDocUrls({...docUrls, statementUrl:item.url})
          }})
```

Comment: `res.data` is array of single object ?

Comment: You'd be better to use Array forEach, instead of map. 
`res.data.forEach( ...same stuff )`

Comment: @devcrazy what is `Object.forEach`?

Comment: ah, I mean array forEach

Comment: You don't need an if/else - you can do it with one line using a dynamic key: ``setDocUrls({...obj, [`${item.type}Url`]: item.url });``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDocUrls` is asynchronous so you're just overwriting `docUrls` everytime you call it.

Having multiple `setDocUrls({...docUrls, imageUrl:item.url})` will just keep overwriting the previous call due to the `...docUrls`.

Instead, make a copy of docUrl.

```
const docUrlCopy = { ...docUrls }
res.data.map(item=>{
      if(item.type === 'image'){
        docUrlCopy.imageUrl = item.url

      }else if(item.type  === 'pan'){
        docUrlCopy.panUrl = item.url
      }else  
        docUrlCopy.statementUrl = item.url                 
      }})
setDocUrls(docUrlCopy) // only 1 call
```